# Subset lineal regression in R

Tags: r

I have the following formula:

```
Reg_Total<- In_Bigdata2 %>%  
        lm(log(This_6) ~ This_1+This_2+This_3+This_4+
                   This_5+This_7+This_8+
                   This_12+This_13+This_14+This_15+This_16+This_17,This_18,data = .)
```

With that [data](https://github.com/brianamaya01/test_subset/blob/main/Test.xlsx?raw=true)

With only the variable **This_18** as a subset, do you know why it gives me a perfect regression with an r2 of 1?

Comment: Did you check the correlation between 6 (target) and 18? Likely 18 „explains“ 6 very (too) well. Check the VIF https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64394/how-to-interpret-variance-inflation-factor-vif-results/64415#64415

Comment: if I look at it in fact it is 0.18, I think the problem is in subset try to do it with other equations, different variables and I get an R2 of 1

Comment: When I run the model above, This_18 is an unspecified subset and I get R2 1, I try it with other variables and it comes out the same.

Comment: @benBolker what intrigues me is the subset This_18 that by not specifying a value I get an R2 of 1

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was a good puzzle.

You have to dig a little bit to find out what the `subset=` argument does, as it gets passed to the `model.frame()` function inside `lm()`. From `?model.frame()`:

> subset: a specification of the rows to be used: defaults to all rows.
> This can be **any valid indexing vector (see ‘[.data.frame’)
> for the rows of ‘data’** or if that is not supplied, a data
> frame made up of the variables used in ‘formula’.

(emphasis added). Usually people specify a *logical expression* for `subset=` (e.g. `This_5>2`) to restrict the regression to particular cases. If you put in an integer vector, `lm()`/`model.frame()` will select the rows corresponding to those integers.

So ... what `lm()`/`model.frame()` have done is to construct a data set for the linear model that consists of rows of the original data set **indexed by `This_18`**. In other words, since the first few elements of `This_18` are (2,3,4,3,3,2, ...), the first row of the new data set will be row 2 of the original data set; the second row will be row 3; the third row will be row 4; the fourth row will be *another copy of row 3*; and so on ...

```r
head(model.frame(This_6~.-This_18, data=dd, subset=This_18))
##     This_6 This_1 This_2 This_3 This_4 This_5 This_7 This_8 This_9 This_10 ...
## 2        2      5      3      3      3      3      3      2      3       1 ...
## 3        3      3      3      3      3      3      3      4      4       4 ...
## 4        1      3      3      3      3      3      3      2      1       2 ...
## 3.1      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      4      4       4 ...
## 3.2      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      4      4       4 ...
## 2.1      2      5      3      3      3      3      3      2      3       1 ...
```

(you can also get this object by running `model.frame(fitted_model)`).

Therefore, since the only values of `This_18` are the integers 1-6, you get a regression run only on **multiple copies of rows 1-6 of the original data set**. Thus it's not surprising that you get a perfect fit, since there are only 6 unique response/sets of predictors.

The remaining question is ... what did you **intend** to do by using `subset=This_18` ... ? "subset" refers to a subset of **observations**, not a subset of **predictors**.

If you want to do **best subset regression** (i.e. find the subset of predictors that maximize some criterion) there is not a single easy answer (and in fact there are some potential statistical pitfalls if you are interested in inference rather than prediction). Googling "R best subset regression" should help you, or [searching for those keywords on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+best+subset+regression). (Or see the `glmulti` package, or the `leaps` package, or the `stepAIC` function in the `MASS` package, or r the `MuMIn` package, or ...)

Comment: thank you so much. I was just a little intrigued by r2 de1. What I would really like to do is obtain the best linear regression model with those variables. Is there a way to get the best model automatically?

Comment: see new paragraph at the end of my answer.